# build up an array of attributes from a configurable

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, product-attribute

Is the best way to build up an array of attributes from a configurable

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable")
{                   
   $simpleProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductCollection($_product);

   $attributeOptions = array();
   foreach ($simpleProducts as $simpleProduct)
   {
       $myproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simpleProduct->getId());
       $baseColour = $myproduct->getAttributeText('basecolour'); 
       $attributeOptions[] = $baseColour
    }
}
```

Comment: have you only one attribute?

Comment: The product has loads of custom attributes but yes I only want to get 1

Answer (score 1):

You could try the function `getConfigurableAttributesAsArray`. This function is on the object `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable`. It should take in a product and return an array of all the configurable attributes attached to the product.

The other options is to build a product collection using `getUsedProductCollection` and then add the attribute you need to the select.